# how does this.tail.next adds node to this.head?

Tags: javascript, data-structures

I am currently watching a tutorial about singly linked list and the tutor's implementation of singly linked list made me pretty confused for push method and i couldnt figure out what's going on.

here it is:

```
class Node {
  constructor(val) {
    this.val = val;
    this.next = null;
  }
}

class SinglyLinkedList {
  constructor() {
    this.length = 0;
    this.head = null;
    this.tail = null;
  }

  push(val) {
    let node = new Node(val);
    if (!this.head) {
      this.head = node;
      this.tail = this.head;
    } else {
      this.tail.next = node;
      this.tail = node;
    }

    this.length++;
    return this;
  }

let list = new SinglyLinkedList();
list.push('hello');
list.push('goodbye');
}
```

In this code, i am having really hard time to understand how **this.tail.next** inserts a new node to **this.head**.
For the first insertion it's clear that both head and tail point to same object which is the first node. But after the first push, this.tail is assigned a new object and is not same with this.head but this.tail.next still adds new node to the last next property of this.head
How is this happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It may help to visualise how things get done by the `push` method.

When the (empty) linked list is constructed with `let list = new SinglyLinkedList()`, we have this situation (I omit the length property, as it does not relate to the question):

```
 list (this)
  ↓
┌────────────┐
│ head: null │
│ tail: null │
└────────────┘
```

The main code then calls `list.push('hello')`. This starts with creating a node instance, and the local variable `node` references it:

```
 list              node
  ↓                 ↓
┌────────────┐    ┌──────────────┐
│ head: null │    │ val: "hello" │
│ tail: null │    │ next: null   │
└────────────┘    └──────────────┘
```

As `this.head` is `null`, the `if` block gets executed. First `this.head = node` results in this state:

```
 list              node
  ↓                 ↓
┌────────────┐    ┌──────────────┐
│ head: ────────> │ val: "hello" │
│ tail: null │    │ next: null   │
└────────────┘    └──────────────┘
```

And then that reference is copied into `this.tail`:

```
 list              node
  ↓                 ↓
┌────────────┐    ┌──────────────┐
│ head: ────────> │ val: "hello" │
│ tail: ────────> │ next: null   │
└────────────┘    └──────────────┘
```

After the length is updated, the `push('hello')` call has done its job and the `node` variable is disposed. Then `list.push('goodbye')` is executed. We again start by creating a node:

```
 list                                  node
  ↓                                     ↓
┌────────────┐    ┌──────────────┐    ┌────────────────┐
│ head: ────────> │ val: "hello" │    │ val: "goodbye" │
│ tail: ────────> │ next: null   │    │ next: null     │
└────────────┘    └──────────────┘    └────────────────┘
```

Now `this.head` is not `null` and so we get into the `else` block. `this.tail.next = node` is executed, and so we get (just follow the arrows from `this` to `tail` to `next` where the `null` is replaced with a reference to `node`):

```
 list                                  node
  ↓                                     ↓
┌────────────┐    ┌──────────────┐    ┌────────────────┐
│ head: ────────> │ val: "hello" │    │ val: "goodbye" │
│ tail: ────────> │ next: ──────────> │ next: null     │
└────────────┘    └──────────────┘    └────────────────┘
```

Then `this.tail = node` gets executed. This replaces an existing reference with another, restoring the invariant that `list.tail` always references the last node:

```
 list                                  node
  ↓                                     ↓
┌────────────┐    ┌──────────────┐    ┌────────────────┐
│ head: ────────> │ val: "hello" │    │ val: "goodbye" │
│ tail: ───────┐  │ next: ──────────> │ next: null     │
└────────────┘ │  └──────────────┘┌─> └────────────────┘ 
               └──────────────────┘
```

Again, the `node` variable's life ends at the end of the execution, and so we are left with `list` and the dependent structure depicted above.

Answer (score 2):

> But after the first push, `this.tail` is assigned a new object and is not same with `this.head`

That's not correct. After the first insertion, `this.head` and `this.tail` point to the same object:

```
if (!this.head) {
  this.head = node;
  this.tail = this.head;
}
```

For any subsequent insertion, `this.tail` points to the previously inserted node. `this.tail.next` is updated **before** the new node is assigned to `this.tail`:

```
this.tail.next = node;
this.tail = node;
```

That means when the second insertion happens, `this.tail` and `this.head` still point to the same object. `this.tail.next = node` is executed thus updating `this.head.next` as well. Only *after* that assignment is `this.tail` updated to point to the new node.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have one question too, how the nesting of next's are accomplished with this approach, i mean it calls this.tail.next but it inserts node to the latest next property of this.head?